# How do I pass a variable to a macro and evaluate it before macro execution?

Tags: julia

If I have a method

```
macro doarray(arr)
    if in(:head, fieldnames(typeof(arr))) && arr.head == :vect
        println("A Vector")
    else
        throw(ArgumentError("$(arr) should be a vector"))
    end
end
```

it works if I write this

```
@doarray([x])
```

or

```
@doarray([:x])
```

but the following code rightly does not work, raising the `ArgumentError`(i.e. `ArgumentError: alist should be a vector`).

```
alist = [:x]
@doarray(alist)
```

How can I make the above to act similarly as @doarray([x])

Motivation:
I have a recursive macro(say `mymacro`) which takes a vector, operates on the first value and then calls recursively `mymacro` with the rest of the vector(say `rest_vector`). I can create `rest_vector`, print the value correctly(for debugging) but I don't know how to evaluate `rest_vector` when I feed it to the `mymacro` again.

EDIT 1:
I'm trying to implement [logic programming](https://mullr.github.io/micrologic/literate.html) in Julia, namely MiniKanren. In the Clojure implementation that I am basing this off, the code is such.

```
(defmacro fresh
  [var-vec & clauses]
  (if (empty? var-vec)
    `(lconj+ ~@clauses)
    `(call-fresh (fn [~(first var-vec)]
                   (fresh [~@(rest var-vec)]
                     ~@clauses)))))
```

My failing Julia code based on that is below. I apologize if it does not make sense as I am trying to understand macros by implementing it.

```
macro fresh(varvec, clauses...)
    if isempty(varvec.args)
        :(lconjplus($(esc(clauses))))
    else
        varvecrest = varvec.args[2:end]
        return quote
            fn = $(esc(varvec.args[1])) -> @fresh($(varvecvest), $(esc(clauses)))
            callfresh(fn)
        end
    end
end
```

The error I get when I run the code `@fresh([x, y], ===(x, 42))`(you can disregard `===(x, 42)` for this discussion)

```
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: UndefVarError: varvecvest not defined
```

The problem line is `fn = $(esc(varvec.args[1])) -> @fresh($(varvecvest), $(esc(clauses)))`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly it is better to call a function (not a macro) inside a macro that will operate on AST passed to the macro. Here is a simple example how you could do it:

```
function recarray(arr)
    println("head: ", popfirst!(arr.args))
    isempty(arr.args) || recarray(arr)
end

macro doarray(arr)
    if in(:head, fieldnames(typeof(arr))) && arr.head == :vect
        println("A Vector")
        recarray(arr)
    else
        throw(ArgumentError("$(arr) should be a vector"))
    end
end
```

Of course in this example we do not do anything useful. If you specified what exactly you want to achieve then I might suggest something more specific.

Comment: Bogumil Kaminski. I have added EDIT 1 to give you more context(though I fear it may make it more confusing..). Thanks for trying.

Comment: The use case is too complex for me to work it out now. However, there are two things I can recommend from the experience: 1) try first writing a function that takes an expression and returns an expression and make sure it gives you what you want; next turn it into a macro; 2) have the input and output expressions written down and use `@macroexpand` macro to see if your macro produces what you want. If this does not help you I will try to have a look at your specific example in a few days.

Comment: will try that. Thanks Bogumil :)